# What happens to skewness as you play the same gamble multiple times?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, moment-generating-functions, gambling, lotteries

Suppose there is a probability distribution $p$, over money outcomes.
Suppose one draws $N$ times from $p$, with replacement, and takes the average money outcome over these $N$ draws. Call this probabilistic process process "$(N; p)$".

For any $N' > N''$, it is clear that the variance of $(N'; p)$ is smaller than the variance of $(N''; p)$, and that both have the same expected value.

But what happens to skewness? Is the skewness of $(N'; p)$ also always smaller than the skewness of $(N''; p)$?

Comment: I’m thinking that under nice conditions, the sample mean approaches a normal distribution for large $N$, by CLT. So the skewness should be well-behaved too in those cases, right?

Comment: (If CLT fails on $p$, I don’t know enough to say anything clever)

Comment: That's my intuition too, but in this case I'm interested not only in the limit but in the process. For example, it's mechanical that the variance is smaller the larger N gets. I'm wondering if there's a mechanical skewness relation or if one can only appeal to limit arguments.